# Sliding drawer with nested content

Tags: android

I have a simple doubt. I want the sliding drawer content to have a linear layout for content (vertical) which has 2 linear layouts again inside it. Both horizontal. However, doing this shows only the first horizontal linear layout on drawing the sliding drawer not the second.

Code:

```
<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle"

    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/up1"
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"  />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout android:weightSum="5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/wififilled"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="30dp" />
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/bluetoothfill"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="30dp" />
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/speaker"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="30dp" />
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/sunxfilled"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="30dp" />
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/bulbfilled"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="30dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:weightSum="8"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/sunx"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3.5"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/brightbar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/red_scrubber_progress"
                android:thumb="@drawable/red_scrubber_control"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dip" >
            </SeekBar>
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/sunxfilled"
                android:layout_weight="3.5"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```

Image: [image: Only one linear layout horizontal is shown]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

and in in this Drawer Layout you can use framelayout which give you to add multiple layout.

which gives you more UI function or you can show me more code for your hel

Comment: and your expected view...? or you can try with only view is it visible or not that way you can get what is visible and what is in hidden part.

Answer (score 0):

Change your linear layout height from 'match_parent' to 'wrap_content' like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:weightSum="5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```